# How can I allow only "-" at first character in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I'm using React-native
I made a regex that accepts only numbers. Here, I want to allow one minus at the beginning only. That is, I want to create a regular expression that allows "-" only once, but can be used or not. So I applied my code, but it doesn't work. How do I fix my regular expression?

The restriction is that the minus must not be placed in the middle of or after the number, only at the beginning of the number, and the minus can be used or not.

```
       let minCheck = !/^[0-9]{1,4}$/g.test("-1")
```

i tried

```
       let minCheck = /-?!/^[0-9]{1,4}$/g.test(valueRange.minValue)
```

but it doesn't work

How can i fix my code?

Comment: Why not `^-?[0-9]{1,4}$`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following will fix your issue(in case you want to make minus sign compulosry):

```
/(-)([0-9]{1,4})/
```

In case you want to make minus sign optional, please try this:

```
/([-0-9]{1,4})/
```

If either of these don't work for you, please ask and I'll make one accordingly for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below regEx:

Exp 1:
/^(-)?\d+$/g.test("-213213")

Exp 2:
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d*)$/g.test("12321")

- "-" with ? makes it non-mandatory
- d+ expects more than 1 digits
- Exp 1 allows start with 0 for ex: "-0" or "0123" will also be true. If you want to restrict that. Use Exp 2

Comment: your regex is great but i want to input only limit number like this
[0-9]{1,4} How can i fix this?

Comment: You can try this /^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work i want to input only 1~9 number but if i used your code i have no limit

Comment: New expression I sent '/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g' should limit the numbers length to "4". At the same time it will not allow numbers starting with 0 like "0123"

Comment: no it doesn't work i set (-11111111)  i can still input

Comment: Here are some of the test Results

/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("-11111111")
false
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("-1111")
true
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("0")
true
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("1234")
true
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("12345")
false
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("-0")
false
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("0123")
false
/^(0|(-)?[1-9]\d{3})$/g.test("12345")
false